I am quoting someone, but instead of using parentheses he used brackets, but I don't want the reader to think I wrote what's inside those brackets
The quote I am using is the following: "used indifferently to denote the Byzantines and the Christians of the Melkite [i.e. Orthodox] Greek rite who lived in Muslim territory."
Am I allowed to remove "[i.e. Orthodox]"? In my next paragraph I make it clear that a Melkite can be either an Orthodox or a Catholic; it would be confusing if the reader thought I meant in the previous paragraph that a Melkite is simply an Orthodox.

You may signal that you have omitted a part of the quoted text by inserting an ellipsis in it's stead:

"used indifferently to denote the Byzantines and the Christians of the Melkite ... Greek rite who lived in Muslim territory."

If you retain the original brackets, you should state in the source citation that the quoted matter already includes brackets of its own (CMOS 6.99):

"used indifferently to denote the Byzantines and the Christians of the Melkite [i.e. Orthodox] Greek rite who lived in Muslim territory." (Gibb, 1962; brackets in the original)


Notes
What you quote is already a quotation (from Sauvaget) in your source (Gibb) and the comment in square brackets was added to the quotation by your source author (Gibb). You should ideally get the original source (Sauvaget) and quote it directly, or tell your readers that you are quoting a quote, e.g. "..." (Jean Sauvaget, La Mosquée omeyyade de Médine, Paris, 1947, p. 111f., quoted after Gibb, 1962, p. 54).
CMOS recommends to give the original author in the surrounding text, e.g.:

Jean Sauvaget wrote in La Mosquée omeyyade de Médine in 1947: "..." (Gibb, 1962, p. 54).

Also, you say that in the text following that quotation you want to make clear that a Melkite rite can be either Greek Orthodox or Catholic. Please note, though, that the author you quote (Gibb!) explicitly understood a Melkite rite to be Orthodox (as indicated by his comment in square brackets). If you delete that explanation and replace it with an explanation that Melkite rites can be Greek Orthodox or Catholic, you may be misrepresenting your source (Gibb). It might be better to keep the original explanation and ammend it with your own, e.g.

Contrary to what Gibb believed, Melkite rites can be Greek Orthodox or Catholic.

or, as I recommened above, to cite the original source (Sauvaget). That way you don't have to edit the quotation and deal with the interpretation of the secondary source author (Gibb), with which you apparently disagree.

Add your own brackets to the quote.  Namely add "[sic]".  This indicates that you are quoting what he said without supporting it.
